# How to scrape data from an ASP website using Java?

Tags: java, asp.net, web-scraping

I have an ASP website from which I am trying to scrape data. The website has a search page which returns result after showing a progress-bar. The result is returned on the same page. I am writing the scraping script on Java. However, it keeps on showing me the web-page without results. I need the result contents which are displayed on the same page.

I am sending the parameters in a post request and I expect the result page to be shown.
I have tried using HtmlUnit and basic Java's request-response however, it didnt work. 
Please assist me with it. Bellow is my code snippet; just in case.

```
        URL url = new URL(base_url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        response = print_content(connection);
        String viewstate = get_view_state(response);
        connection.disconnect();

        url_params = "my-necessary-url-params";

        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST);
        request .setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        request .setRequestBody(url_params);

        try {
            HtmlPage page = client.getPage(cswa_request);
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Any help or view-points are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The web site is probably loading the search results via AJAX. You need to find out the URL for that API.

Comment: @Thilo There is no AJAX request. It is just one database result which is displayed.

Comment: In case you downvote; please mention the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) - works fine even with dynamic content creation (AJAX and the like). Heaps of tutorials on the net.

Comment: Yes. I tried Selenium as well. However, IMHO Selenium and HtmlUnit produce the same result.